# maximum recursion depth exceeded when exec `repr()`

Tags: python, recursion, repr

```
class A(object):
    def xx(self):
        return 'xx'


class B(A):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ss%s' % self.xx

b = B()
print repr(b)
```

When I wrote `__repr__` method, I forgot to call `self.xx`.

Why these code cause `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`.

My English is poor, hope you guys can understand these. Thank you very much!

Comment: @skyking: yes, the OP realises this. They state *in the question* that they forgot to call `self.xx`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what happens:

- `%s` on `self.xx` calls `str(self.xx)`
- A method has no `__str__`, so `__repr__` is called on it instead.
- The `__repr__` for a method incorporates the `repr()` of `self` as `<bound method [classname].[methodname] of [repr(self)]>`:

  ```
  >>> class A(object):
  ...     def xx(self):
  ...         pass
  ...
  >>> A().xx
  <bound method A.xx of <__main__.A object at 0x1007772d0>>
  >>> A.__repr__ = lambda self: '<A object with __repr__>'
  >>> A().xx
  <bound method A.xx of <A object with __repr__>>
  ```
- The `__repr__` of `self` tries to use `'ss%s' % self.xx`

and so you have an infinite loop.